# Chrome >50: Where can I see the negotiated cipher suite?

Tags: tls, chrome

This is about Chrome 50 and later. When visiting an https site, where can I find the negotiated cipher suite?
I know where to find this info in previous versions of Chrome but I'm not able to find it in versions greater or equal to 50.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Update:**

More recent Chrome versions make it both easier and harder.

The bad news: The “Details” link has been removed. Now you have to open the Developer Tools with `Crtl`+`Shift`+`I` or `Cmd`+`Opt`+`I`, or by clicking on the ⋮ Chrome menu > “More tools” > “Developer tools”, and then click on the “Security” tab.

More positively, the information has now been added to the “ Overview” section without reloading, and includes the key exchange group (e.g. the elliptic curve P-256).

---

another update: in the newest versions [I'm on the 64 bit version 59.0.3071.115] looks like there is a specific security tab to display this info in the Developer Tools:

[image: chrome_security_info]

---

**Original Instructions**

1. Click on the  lock icon in the location bar
2. Click on the “Details” link next to “Your connection to this site is private.” This opens the Security tab of the Developer Tools.
3. Reload the page.
4. The Security thing’s left column goes “ Overview”, “Main Origin”… Click on the next one, “⚫ https://security.stackexchange.com”.

   ```
   Connection

       Protocol  TLS 1.2
   Key Exchange  ECDHE_ECDSA
   Cipher Suite  AES_128_GCM
   ```

Yay!

[image: Picture of Developer Tools Security Tab as described]

Comment: Used to be much more handy in previous versions. Now the console has to be opened to get the info.

Comment: It used to also display whether it was using an obsolete cipher suite too. Now I have to look it up to check whether it's an obsolete one.

Comment: It **doesn't show details** like what SHA has been used, e.g. SHA256 and whether it was with P-256 elliptic curve [FIPS186]. I know that because I configured the cipher suite order.

Comment: In Chrome 69 it's all under the Security tab in in the Developer's Tools. Here you can see the protocol, the hash algorithm, and the certificate details. It will also give you details about the reliability of the cipher used.